# Azure Artifacts - Sharing project-scoped feeds with other projects

Tags: azure-devops, artifacts, azure-artifacts

We have a number of projects within my organisation. One such project has created a project-scoped Azure Artifact feed that they wish to share with our other projects.

However, when the other projects access their Artifacts page, from the feed drop-down they can only see the "Organization scoped feeds" and nothing under "Project-scoped feeds". What do we need to do make this feed visible and available to the other projects, particularly for use in their pipelines.

I'm at a loss, as I've drawn a complete blank so far.

Comment: Hi, Not get your latest information, are the answers below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/project-scoped-feeds?view=azure-devops#understanding-the-difference-between-an-organization-scoped-feed-and-a-project-scoped-feed): To see a project-scoped feed in the list you have to be navigated to the project the feed is scoped to. We could know that we cannot see the project-scoped feed in another project.

> particularly for use in their pipelines.

When connecting to a private project scoped feed from an Azure DevOps pipeline that is in the same organization but in a different project, the project that the feed is scoped to must allow access to the other project's build service. The build service must also be separately added to the feed permissions, regardless of the scope of the feed.

1. **Add build service account**: Build service account is `Project Collection Build Service (Org name)`, we need configure feed permission in the project-scoped feed for this service. then we could access the project-scoped feed in the pipeline.

[image]

2. We also need open project settings->settings and ensure the option `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines` and `Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines` is disabled. We could refer to the pic below.

[image]

Then we could access and use the project-scoped feed in another project pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, the combination of these two finally worked for me. Just for the clarification, the second step applies to the project consuming the feed and restoring packages from it, not the project owning the feed.

Comment: Is there any equivalent for user accounts, not just pipelines? I want to give users of a different project access to the feed in Visual Studio without giving access to the project itself.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very old post. But, in case, someone is still facing the problem and the above solutions have not worked like me then please follow as below.

**Step One:**

1. Select project hosting the feed
2. Select Project settings
3. Select Permissions
4. Select groups tab
5. Select Contributors
6. Select Members tab
7. Click Add
8. Select [Name of the project Consuming the Feed] Build Services ([Organization Name]) ex: FeedConsumer Build Services (xyz)
9. Click Save

[image]

**Step Two:**

1. Select project hosting the feed
2. Select Artifacts
3. Select your feed.
4. Select Feed Settings
5. Select Permissions
6. Click Add Users/Groups button
7. Select [Name of the project Consuming the Feed] Build Services ([Organization Name]) ex: FeedConsumer Build Services (xyz)
8. Select the role as a contributor
9. Click Save

[image]

**Step Four:**

Add nuGet.config file to the consumer project's root path where there is a .csproj or .sln file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="[Feed Name]" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[Company Name]/[Project Name]/_packaging/[Feed Name]/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Follow these steps to get the above xml

1. Select project hosting the feed
2. Select Artifacts
3. Select the required feed
4. Click Connect to Feed
5. Select NuGet.exe
6. It should be there in Project Setup

[image]

This should allow you to use the feed in one project to another project without giving you an unauthorized error. Happy Coding!!

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/project-scoped-feeds-pipeline-project-permissions?view=azure-devops

Comment: Upon searching the entire Internet this was the most accurate and detailed instructions I found. You should send this to MS so that they update their documentation. Thank you very much my friend

Comment: This works as advertised - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Project-scoped feeds can't be 'shared' with other projects per se, but that doesn't really restrict how they are *used*. You can certainly have identities with permission to both, including build identities. Make sure the identity has "Read project-level information" permission in the project security settings for the project which contains the feed, as well as appropriate permissions on the feed itself. You can think of it similarly to Git repos -- you don't see other projects' Git repos, but there's nothing stopping you from using Git repos in multiple projects if you have permission to access them.

Another option is [Upstream Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops).

Comment: that's odd because I have definitely seen in other similar instances where a project-scoped feed owned by one team project, was available/visible from the dropdown list of another team project feed.

Comment: If `View project-level information` of the project hosting the feed is granted, its Boards and Repos can be accessed as well. Most of the time, this is not intended. Although the access to the Repos can be further restricted albeit more steps have to be taken. However I couldn't find a way to disable the view access to the Boards.

Comment: "View project-level information" is required to access a project, period. The Azure DevOps infrastructure rejects requests to projects where the calling identity does not have that permission.