# Why are Organization-Scoped Feeds discouraged in Azure Artifacts, as opposed to Project-Scoped Feeds?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I use DevOps Server 2020, and am trying to integrate Azure Artifacts into our workflow.

In all of the documentation, Azure Artifacts specifically states that they do not recommend Organization-Scoped Feeds. Why is this?

I am looking to provide common packages to all of the projects, and Organization-Scoped Feeds looks like what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are Organization-Scoped Feeds discouraged in Azure Artifacts, as opposed to Project-Scoped Feeds?

That is because there may be a pblic project in our organization, or some projects will be made public later. Then at this time it is required that the feed is also public. But if the project is private, the feed is also private.

So, to avoid your project will be turned public in the future and you want your feed to remain private, it is recommended that you use Project-Scoped Feeds.

Of course, you can still use Organization-Scoped Feeds if you know the difference and implications between Organization-Scoped Feeds and Project-Scoped Feeds, but you need to be extra cautious.

You could check the document [Project-scoped vs organization-scoped feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/project-scoped-feeds?view=azure-devops) for some details.

**Besides**, Project-scoped feeds can't be 'shared' with other projects as default, but that doesn't really restrict how they are used. We can allow other projects to share Project-Scoped Feeds with additional settings:

You could refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64821831/azure-artifacts-sharing-project-scoped-feeds-with-other-projects/64852034#64852034) for how to implement it.